# python create hierarchy from parent-child list

Tags: python, recursion

Given the following list:

```
a = [
{'parent': 'p1', 'parent_name': 'pn1', 'child': 'c1', 'child_name': 'cn1'},
{'parent': 'p1', 'parent_name': 'pn1', 'child': 'c2', 'child_name': 'cn2'},
{'parent': 'c1', 'parent_name': 'cn1', 'child': 'c3', 'child_name': 'cn3'},
{'parent': 'c1', 'parent_name': 'cn1', 'child': 'c4', 'child_name': 'cn4'},
{'parent': 'c4', 'parent_name': 'cn4', 'child': 'c5', 'child_name': 'cn5'},
{'parent': 'c2', 'parent_name': 'cn2', 'child': 'c6', 'child_name': 'cn6'},
{'parent': 'c3', 'parent_name': 'cn3', 'child': 'c7', 'child_name': 'cn7'}
]
```

I want to create a hierarchical dict of lists
So far I've made this code which runs fine, but for some reason the children c3 and c4 are repeated twice.
Where did I made a mistake?

```
def build(key):

    children = [(item['child'], item['child_name']) for item in a if item['parent'] == key]

    data = {}
    for k, name in children:
        data[k] = {'child': k, 'child_name': name, 'children': []}
        for item in a:
            if item['parent'] == k:
                data[k]['children'].append(build(k))

    return data
```

**EDIT:**
The code above produce this output:

```
{'c1': {'child': 'c1',
        'child_name': 'cn1',
        'children': [{'c3': {'child': 'c3',
                             'child_name': 'cn3',
                             'children': [{'c7': {'child': 'c7',
                                                  'child_name': 'cn7',
                                                  'children': []}}]},
                      'c4': {'child': 'c4',
                             'child_name': 'cn4',
                             'children': [{'c5': {'child': 'c5',
                                                  'child_name': 'cn5',
                                                  'children': []}}]}},
                     {'c3': {'child': 'c3',
                             'child_name': 'cn3',
                             'children': [{'c7': {'child': 'c7',
                                                  'child_name': 'cn7',
                                                  'children': []}}]},
                      'c4': {'child': 'c4',
                             'child_name': 'cn4',
                             'children': [{'c5': {'child': 'c5',
                                                  'child_name': 'cn5',
                                                  'children': []}}]}}]},
 'c2': {'child': 'c2',
        'child_name': 'cn2',
        'children': [{'c6': {'child': 'c6',
                             'child_name': 'cn6',
                             'children': []}}]}}
```

I would need the exact same output but obviously without the duplications (here the children of c1 are repeated twice)

Comment: could you please provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: If you run the code you can see the problem. But I've edited my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`c3`, for example, is repeated twice because of line 2 below:

```
data[k] = {'child': k, 'child_name': name, 'children': []}
for item in a: # 'c3' will be found twice in a
  if item['parent'] == k:
```

Because `c3` occurs twice in `a`, you add its children twice.

I'm not sure why you need to do that loop. To me it looks like it'll work if you remove that loop and just do `data[k]['children'].append(build(k))` below `data[k] = {'child': k, 'child_name': name, 'children': []}`:

```
data[k] = {'child': k, 'child_name': name, 'children': []}
data[k]['children'].append(build(k))
```

Comment: Thanks! That was the problem!